# Kendo MVC Core - Grid - unable to get data with routes - 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have just started a new contract and althought I am used to using Kendo, this is my first experience using Kendo Core.

Typically I would have my controller, and my action and bind on this using

```
.DataSource(ds => ds.Read(r => r.Action("RefreshRecommendationGridData", "ReportLookup")))
```

However the firm that I am at heavily uses routing

```
 [Authorize]
[Route("report-lookups")]
public class ReportLookupController : Controller
{
    [AccessRights("Lists")]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("report-lesson-recommendations/manage")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RefreshRecommendationGridData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var result = await _cacheService.SearchForReportLessonRecommendationsAsync(null);
        return Json(result.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }
}
```

When attempting this and looking through developer tools and the network and when using

```
.DataSource(ds => ds.Read(r => r.Url("manage"))
```

I get a 400 Bad Reqest error.

I guess I am missing something, however what that is I am at a complete loss. I suspect its something quite simple, however, I cannot find anything on Telerik site that will help.

If I change this to a `[HttpGet]` then this is returned as a 404 error.

I have tried the most basic of calls in a new controller with no routing and as per a vanilla example, however I get the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found my answer, and albeit through a lot of stubling in the dark and no use or valuable response from Telerik themselves.

```
.Read(r => r.Action("RefreshRecommendationGridData", "ReportLookup").Data("sendAntiForgery"))
```

and then in the javascript

```
function sendAntiForgery() {
    return { "__RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val() }
}
```